# Uso da vírgula em "Quem ama, cuida."

Tags: pontuação, vírgula

Como se justifica o uso da vírgula na oração “quem ama, cuida”?

Comment: Eu poria a vírgula para marcar a ligeira pausa na fala. Deve outra razão baseada na sintaxe.

Answer (score 9):

Ou “*justifica-se o uso da vírgula na oração ‘quem ama, cuida’* ”?

Eu diria que as duas estão corretas porque aqui há um sujeito oracional e vai depender de como se vê a frase.

- Aqui há um sujeito = *Quem*
- Que pratica uma ação = *ama*
- Aqui há um sujeito = *Quem ama*
- Que pratica uma ação = *cuida*

A isto dá-se o nome de *sujeito oracional*.

Quando há um sujeito oracional pode-se ou não - *embora eu ache que usar é  preferível* - usar, dependendo de como se vê a frase.

É o sujeito “*quem*” que pratica a ação ou é o sujeito “*quem ama*” que pratica a ação? Eu diria que é uma questão estilística.

Lê [*A vírgula, o sujeito e o predicado* (Ciberdúvidas)](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-virgula-o-sujeito-e-o-predicado/22857):

> Por último, refira-se que há um caso em que é possível (mas, atenção,
>   não obrigatório) pôr vírgula entre sujeito e predicado: depois de
>   «sujeito expandido pela oração adjetiva» (ver Bechara, idem, pág.
>   610): «Os que falam em matérias que não entendem, parecem fazer gala
>   da sua própria ignorância» (Marquês de Maricá).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Gostei muito de saber do caso em que é possível inserir a vírgula entre sujeito e predicado.

Comment: Achei este artigo, muito pertinente: [Quem estuda, separa sujeito de predicado com vírgula?](http://veja.abril.com.br/blog/sobre-palavras/consultorio/quem-estuda-separa-sujeito-de-predicado-com-virgula/)